# MVC send model data to anothers sub model in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, parameter-passing

I have a model that contain a model else. And in view I want to send data to this model's property with  althoug other properties fine, Sub model nothing gets.. 
Whats the problem ?
Is there any way to do this ?

```
 public class CalculateIndexVM
        {
            public int KimyasalId { get; set; }      
            public double Miktar { get; set; }
            public IndexCalculationModel indexCalculationMdl { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

and part of form in view:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="KimyasalId" value="@Model.KimyasalId" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="KimyasalId " value="@Model.KimyasalId " />
                            <input type="hidden" name="Miktar" value="@Model.Miktar" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="indexCalculationMdl" value="@Model.indexCalculationMdl" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write out each of the `IndexCalculationModel` properties out in your view.  For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="KimyasalId" value="@Model.KimyasalId" />
<input type="hidden" name="KimyasalId " value="@Model.KimyasalId " />
<input type="hidden" name="Miktar" value="@Model.Miktar" />
<input type="hidden" name="indexCalculationMdl.PropOne" value="@Model.indexCalculationMdl.PropOne" />
<input type="hidden" name="indexCalculationMdl.PropTwo" value="@Model.indexCalculationMdl.PropTwo" />
```

going off the information i have, to send with json you would just need to mirror the model you accept.

```
{
   KimyasalID: kimyasalVal,
   Miktar: "same",
   indexCalculationMdl:
   {
        PropOne : "foo"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually its hard a bit because there also sub domain in it :) What about send it with json ?

Comment: Edited to add answer to json